# How can I create this analyzer game with html/css/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to recreate a type of analyzer game (found here - http://kelowna.myezrock.com/showusyourholidayspirit) so that it will work on mobile. It is currently done with flash. I would like to be able to easily rebrand the colours/images but essentially the game will work the same as the link.

All examples I can find are quiz games that give you a score at the end. Any ideas are very welcome!

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Where are you stuck? Show your code.

Comment: I was hoping to be pointed in the right direction of an example or a starting point. All of the javascript quiz tutorials and examples seem to only offer a final score at the end as opposed to 1 of 4 results based on the answers. Any suggestions?

Comment: Associate each choice to a drink and count the points for each. At the end, get the drink that has the most points (choices that are related to them).

Comment: Thanks, Blex. Any chance you know of any examples or tutorials for creating this?

Comment: I'm making a JS Fiddle right now.

Comment: That's great, thanks blex. Shoot me an email rangerkev@gmail.com when you get a chance. Might be able to help you out as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do it. First you need to define your final results, and set their scores to `0`.

```
var results = [
    {points: 0, name: 'red'},
    {points: 0, name: 'green'},
    /* ... */
];
```

as well as your questions:

```
var questions = [
    {
        question : 'What flower do you prefer?',
        answers : [
                { text: 'poppy', result: 0 },
                { text: 'corn-flower', result: 2 },
                { text: 'sunflower', result: 3 },
                { text: 'artichoke', result: 1 }
        ]
    },
    /* ... */
];
```

You'll need to have a couple of functions to do the job as well as a couple of variables:

```
var qEl = document.getElementById('question'),
aEl = document.getElementsByClassName('answer'),
res = document.getElementById('result'),
cur = -1,
question;

// displays the next question
function nextQuestion(){
    cur++;
    question = questions[cur];
    qEl.innerHTML = (cur+1) + ' - ' + question.question;
    for(var i=0; i<aEl.length; i++){
        aEl[i].innerHTML = question.answers[i].text;
    }
}

// add 1 to the related result and shows next question
function answer(num){
    var result = results[question.answers[num].result];
    result.points = result.points + 1;
    if(cur>=questions.length-1){
        for(var i=0, len=aEl.length; i<len; i++){
            aEl[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
        qEl.style.display = 'none';
        res.style.display = 'block';
        res.innerHTML = 'Your favorite color seems to be ' + getMaxScore() + '!';
        res.className = getMaxScore();
    } else {
        nextQuestion();
    }
}

// gets the name of the result with the max score
function getMaxScore(){
    var maxPoints = 0;
    var maxName = '';
    for(var i=0, len=results.length; i<len; i++){
        if(results[i].points>maxPoints){
            maxPoints = results[i].points;
            maxName = results[i].name;
        }
    }
    return maxName;
}
```

Then you can show the first question and bind the `answer()` function to the `onclick` event of the answer elements.

```
nextQuestion();

for(var i=0, len=aEl.length; i<len; i++){
    (function(index){
        aEl[i].onclick = function(){
            answer(index);    
        }
    })(i);
}
```

Oh, and here is the HTML:

```
<h2 id="question"></h2>
<p class="answer"></p>
<p class="answer"></p>
<p class="answer"></p>
<p class="answer"></p>
<h1 id="result"></h1>
```

### Wanna try?

Comment: This works within the fiddle page but when I import it into my own page it seems to break. Do I need to import a library or anything?

Comment: As you can see, this code binds the click events to HTML elements. In order for this to work, you need to execute the code only when the document is ready or loaded (do a quick search on google or stack overflow). If that does not help, open your console (F12) and tell us what errors you are getting.

Comment: Hi Blex, I added $(function () { and included jquery library and it seems to be working now. Thanks again, huge help.